# How to make a Singleton-Scoped Object Thread-safe (Guice + Owasp ESAPI)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, thread-safety, guice, esapi

I am currently using the Owasp ESAPI to manage authentication in my java web application, and I am injecting the Singleton MyAuthenticator with guice.injectMembers(this).  I would like to step away from this approach and use a guice-created Singleton-Scoped object.  I liked the thread-safety of the ESAPI singleton, and the safety of singletons in general, using Double-Checked Locking, IODH Idiom, or Bloch's Enum INSTANCE style.

What do I need to do to my Guicified Singleton-Scoped Authenticator to make it thread-safe, as well as the ThreadLocal field I am using to get and set my current User?

I would like to make the entire application work with dependency-injection, but don't want it to break upon web-app concurrent access. Any suggestions or common pitfalls?

The ThreadLocal object I am using looks like the code below:

```
private final ThreadLocalUser currentUser = new ThreadLocalUser();

private class ThreadLocalUser extends InheritableThreadLocal<User> {

    @Override
    public User initialValue() {
        return User.ANONYMOUS;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return super.get();
    }

    public void setUser(User newUser) {
        super.set(newUser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know enough about Owasp ESAPI to give a specific answer, but you may have some luck looking into Guice's AOP support. You can intercept all method invocations on the class and provide whatever concurrency behavior you like.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP

Answer (score 0):

Beware using the "Double-Check Locking" pattern in Java. This design pattern doesn't reliably work in Java (for instance, see http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) *unless* you declare the singleton instance as "**volatile**".